# Cannot generate correct HTML from directive tree

Tags: html, angularjs, directive

I have a directive structure that I'm using to simplify the user interface. The implementation of the directives should handle the complexity.  The directive structure is as follows:

```
  <re-widget id="widget_html_content">

      <re-list name="HtmlContent" query="all">

          <re-items each="item">

              <div>
                  <span> {{item.content}} </span>
              </div>

          </re-items>

      </re-list>

  </re-widget>
```

The above should generate HTML of the following flavor:

```
 <div id="widget_html_content">
      <div ng-controller="ListCtrl" name="HtmlContent" query="{}" class="HtmlContent">
            <div ngRepeat="item in ListCtrl.items">
                <div item="item" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
                    <div>
                        <span> {{item.getContent()}} </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is basically a transformation task (transform the directive HTML to the standard HTML) with some caveats. The following are the requirements:

(1) the re-widget creates isolated scopes since it can be reusable in the page, possibly with the same data input

(2) The re-list tag transforms itself to use a ListCtrl, which the ListCtrl knows how to get the list data by using the input NAME and QUERY attributes/parameters

(3) the re-items tag displays each item in the list by using its inner template defined by the user.  So basically it is an ng-repeat over the list items.  However, each item ng-repeated will have its own ItemCtrl controller instance.  The ItemCtrl instance would get a reference to the item model and data so that it can expose an API for the item data.  Note: the item model is the value of the each attribute in the re-items tag.

I have a plunkr with most of the code at http://plnkr.co/edit/Ja0uDb630RYsSjVOGNRb?p=preview

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please see the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.  It's hard to tell what you're asking and your plunker doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry about the code rushed the data mocking a little bit and it wasn't compiling.  And I forgot to include the ItemCtrl.  In any case, I've revised the question a bit adding more details as well updated the plnkr to build successfully.  Any help meeting the requirements would be greatly appreciated!  I'm willing to contribute more comments and clarifications as needed!

Comment: The problem I was having was due to the issue discussed at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874  After working through that entire thread I was able to solve my problem.